# IIFE returned object - reference internal or external object, internally?

Tags: javascript, object, reference, scope, iife

Is there any practical difference between using the internal or external object reference when creating an object using immediately invoked function expression? Example:

```
var external = (function(){
    var internal = {};
    internal.a = function(){
        //... do stuff
    }
    internal.b = function(){
        internal.a();
        // ^ OR v 
        external.a();
    }
    return internal;
})();
```

Both work. The only difference I could think of is possibly `internal` is cleaned up after being invoked if there's no direct calls to it, but that may be moot since the same object lives in `external`. If there's a duplicate, forgive me - I was unable to articulate what I wanted to know well enough for a search engine to give me a clear answer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are the exact same thing *(as @Pointy pointed out, they are the same thing until someone changes `external` on the outside)*, but it just feels weird to use `external` here, and it is not pretty clear because you are using it inside its own definition sort of.

Comment: @Pointy I agree, nice point :). Answer edited to include your comment. Thank you.

Comment: What would happen if I reference `internal` and something changes that reference later on `external`? Does it still point to the original `internal` value or the new `external` one?

Comment: @RandyHall I don't fully understand your comment, but if you change `external` to something or change `internal` the other variable won't be affected.

Comment: @Sniffer thanks that answered it. I was asking to see if the two objects were linked in some way that made changing one affect the other.

Comment: @RandyHall No they aren't linked, they both refer to the same location in memory but when one of them decides it wants to point somewhere else then that's its business. You are welcome, glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

One interesting difference is that the reference to `external` will mean that the lexical scope that contains the external `var` declaration will be pinned from inside the object. That could be interpreted as a memory leak, depending on what happens to the object.